# MySQL - how to fetch the top combinations of data using same table with multiple combinations of records?

Tags: php, mysql

I have table called `response_drilldown` with the following structure.

These are the my table fields and entries:

```
| answer_id | responder_id | question_id | answer        | level_id |
|-----------|--------------|-------------|---------------|----------|
| 1         | 1            | 25          | India         | 1        | 
| 2         | 1            | 25          | Andhrapradesh | 2        |
| 3         | 1            | 25          | Guntur        | 3        |
| 4         | 2            | 25          | India         | 1        |
| 5         | 2            | 25          | Andhrapradesh | 2        |
| 6         | 2            | 25          | Guntur        | 3        |
| 7         | 3            | 25          | India         | 1        |
| 8         | 3            | 25          | Telangana     | 2        |
| 9         | 3            | 25          | Hyderabad     | 3        |
| 10        | 4            | 25          | India         | 1        |
| 11        | 4            | 25          | Telangana     | 2        |
| 12        | 4            | 25          | Warangal      | 3        |
| 13        | 5            | 25          | India         | 1        |
| 14        | 5            | 25          | Telangana     | 2        |
| 15        | 5            | 25          | Nalgonda      | 3        |
| 16        | 6            | 25          | India         | 1        |
| 17        | 6            | 25          | Telangana     | 2        |
| 18        | 6            | 25          | Hyderabad     | 3        |
```

So using the above example, How to get the combination of data using mysql query like :

> India > Andhrapradesh > guntur > 2,
>
> India > Telangana > Hyderabad > 2,
>
> India > Telangana > Warangal > 1,
>
> India > Telangana > Nalgonda > 1,

Can anyone please give me the answer?

Comment: And what've you tried so far?

Comment: +1 for that comment. Of course, we can easily give you the answer. And, no doubt, someone more interested in a few points than in helping you will give it to you. But how will that help you? Are you going to ask us to write a program, line by line, with one S.O question for each line? Do as Paul has asked and at least attempt it. Post your best attempt at a query and explain why it doesn't work. When I do that, I find that 3/4 of my questions don't get posted, because I answer them myself while writing the question and trying to explain the problem to others.

Comment: and let say also that the combination he needs does not even makes sense...

Comment: You're not looking for a combination though are you. The order of the values is important. This is a permutation. In terms of a solution, it's an important difference.

Comment: Hi paul Tomkiel, Mawag, strawberry,  i have getting the top 10 countries, states and cities using above data with this query (select answer, count(*) from response_drilldown where level_id = '1' group by answer (In this quesry change the level_ids i will get top 10 states and cities)), i am tring to get the top 10 combination of country,state,city based on responders. I used below query but responses was wrong. (SELECT level_id,answer,count(*) as cnt FROM response_drilldown  group by answer,level_id)

Comment: Hi All, I got the answer using this query "SELECT a.answer,b.answer,c.answer,count(c.answer) as cnt FROM response_drilldown a , response_drilldown b , response_drilldown c where a.level_id=1 and b.level_id=2 and c.level_id=3 and a.responder_id=b.responder_id and a.responder_id=c.responder_id group by c.answer". Any performance issues is there in this query. Current  we are using MYISAM table. In this table we are running inserts and deletes only. please tell me any performance issues in this query?